# How to get the latest data in the database without using set interval

Tags: php, ajax

I want my user to receive the latest message that his/her chat mate has sent, so i used set interval and ajax and set the interval to 1 second, but i think it will cause lag in my database if I do that since it will continuously retrieve data every 1 second, I don't want it to have a minute of delay because it's a chat message. Is this the proper approach? If not what is the right way to do this?

Comment: Web sockets would suite your need, you could look at http://socketo.me/

Comment: It seems this is the one that I'm looking for, thanks bud.

Comment: For chat systems, websockets are definitely the way to go! Especially if you don't have a dedicated MySQL server, simply because you will run into problems with 100+ users (probebly less). I've written a complete (just close from finished) websocket based chatsystem. Unfortunetely it's in Dutch. Otherwise you could have it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use websockets or if you have a dedicated server you can try any XMPP server.

http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/

Thanks
Pramod